# Periodic solutions to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we take a function $f : \mathbf R^n \longrightarrow \mathbf R^n$ and we consider the maximal solution  $x$ of Cauchy's problem $x'(t)=f(x(t))$ and $x(0)=x_0$ defined on the $I$ a subset of $\mathbf R$. If we suppose that there are $t_1$ and $t_2$ in $I$, $x(t_1)=x(t_2)$, $t_1 \neq t_2$. 
 Show that $x$ is periodic and that $I$=$\mathbf R$.

I think I must use and other function like $y(t)=x(t+t_2-t_1)$ but I don't know what to do after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x(t,x_0)$ be the solution that starts at the point $x_0$. Note that the solution to an autonomous ode satisfies the group property
$$
x(t+\tau,x_0)=x(t,x(\tau,x_0)).
$$
Now, since $x(t_1)=x(t_2)$ there is constant $T> 0$ such that $x(T,x_0)=x(0,x_0)=x_0$. Now consider $x(t+2T,x_0)$. By the group property 
$$
x(t+2T,x_0)=x(t+T,x(T,x_0))=x(t+T,x_0)=x(t,x_0).
$$
Similar reasoning implies that
$$
x(t+kT,x_0)=x(t,x_0),\quad k\in\mathbf Z,
$$
which proves that the solution is defined for all $t\in\mathbf R$ and the solution is actually periodic.